# get query execution time in command prompt

Tags: mysql, performance, benchmark, query-performance

I'm doing this query `select * from rentals`. This table has more than 10,000 rows and it takes more than 4 minutes to retrieve the results.

But I get this time after I get the results: 10000 rows in set (0,05 sec).

Do you know how to get the real execution time?

I try with:

```
set profiling = 1;
select * from rentals;
show profiles;
```

But also appears that the query duration is: 0,5080950.

Comment: Try a similar query with a smaller result, set such as `select count (*) from rentals`. How long does that take to return?

Comment: It shows: 1 row in set (0,02 sec).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In all probability, your query takes half a second to run, but it takes a lot more time to *display* all the results.

The latter depends on the speed of your network and that of your computer and is not really relevant from a performance tuning perspective.

To answer your question, the query execution time (0.5 seconds) *is* the execution time.